# Rest service getting (400) Bad Request for special characters even after serializing with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, rest

I have a restful web service in C# which uses JSON POST for HttpWebRequest. In the client side, input data will be converted to JSON format using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject method. For sending the data IO.Stream with utf-8 encoding is used. I don't have any problem with sending data even with normal specific characters. But for some weird input text like "professional" I got (400) Bad Request error and it seems for this specific case Newtonsoft.Json cannot serialize well.

Any help will be appreciated. The relevant codes are shared below:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(restServiceUrl);
            request.Timeout = int.Parse((cmbTimeout.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Value.ToString()) * 1000;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
var readTextParams = new RESTReadTextParameters();
readTextParams.Text = "professional";
readTextParams.Speaker = "M";
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(readTextParams);

System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
      requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to this problem is using Base64 encoding. A sample of code for encoding the input text is shown below:

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
readTextParams.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encoding.GetBytes(readTextParams.Text.ToCharArray()));
data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(readTextParams);
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
      requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

In the server side, we must decode the Base64 string.